# Edit existing google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used the following command to create a google map on a page:

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);`

I would now like to edit this map, but I do not have the JS object ("map") available. Is there a way that I can get the map object back into javascript (so I can edit it) by reading the "map_canvas" div or by doing something like that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not have the JS object available"? There could be a solution hidden in the context.

Comment: Why can't you access to the map variable anymore ? it seems to be global.

Comment: I loaded the map into the page via ajax, but ajax did not pass the javascript into the main page, so I am left with just a map (without any javascript objects pertaining to that map). I need to be able to modify the map in the main page, but I no longer have access to the original "map" variable.

Comment: This is a valid question without good answer. For example, a third party code could be creating the map and you don't want to change it (think WordPress plugins, e.g.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get this to work by creating a global variable "var globalmap" and then assigning the Google map that gets created "var map = new google.map..." to it "globalmap = map".

I can now refer to "globalmap" in other javascript functions.